# Working with a Model class that has a foreign/navigation key to itself - pt. 2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626475/working-with-a-model-class-that-has-a-foreign-navigation-key-to-itself) question. (I don't have the necessary reputation to post comments to that discussion)

Assuming we have the same model class

```
public class Category
{
   public int CategoryID { get; set; }
   public string CategoryName { get; set; }
   public int? ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
   public string CategoryDesc { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("ParentCategoryID")]
   public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

   [InverseProperty("ParentCategory")]
   public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories{ get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

and use this query

```
var topCategories = dbStore.Categories.ToList().Where(category => category.ParentCategoryID == null);
```

What would be considered best practice for organizing and using the Collection `topCategories`?

I have a similar situation where in my case the `SubCategories` could be 7 or 8 levels deep, and I need to know where each `Category` is within the hierarchy in order to build a View from this data.

I'm using jQuery treetable, and it requires everything to be in the hierarchical order, and for there to be an `id` that references its parent for each `<tr>` in order for the collapsible tree to work.

I believe I can make this work by creating separate variables for each level of the hierarchy (by running queries on `topCategories` and making individual Collections for each level) in the the method that builds the ViewModel and returns the View, but I'm curious to know if there's a cleaner / more elegant way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to what I'm trying to do in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788364/building-ordering-a-tree-as-a-list-in-c-sharp).

I'm certain I didn't ask the original question in a clear enough way, but wanted to add this in case anyone else ended up down the rabbit hole I was in on this subject.

I still have some reading to do on this because I don't fully understand all of it, but what I was ultimately looking for was a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), as referenced in the linked SO post above.

Here is the code from the referenced post, edited for this post.

If anyone is willing to walk through everything that's happening here, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
class FlattenTree
{
  // map each item to its children
  ILookup<Category, Category> mapping;

  public FlattenTree(IEnumerable<Category> list)
  {
    var itemLookup = list.ToDictionary(item => item.ID);
    mapping = list.Where(i => i.ParentCategoryID.HasValue)
                  .ToLookup(i => itemLookup[i.ParentCategoryID.Value]);
  }

  IEnumerable<Item> YieldItemAndChildren(Item node)
  {
    yield return node;
    foreach (var child in mapping[node].OrderBy(i => i.CategoryName))
        foreach (var grandchild in YieldItemAndChildren(child))
            yield return grandchild;
  }

  public IEnumerable<Category> Sort()
  {
    return from grouping in mapping
           let item = grouping.Key
           where item.ParentCategoryID == null
           orderby item.CategoryName
           from child in YieldItemAndChildren(item)
           select child;
  }
}
```